# Google Dataflow - Exclude one PCollection<String> from another PCollection<String>

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have two P-Collection like below

```
P1 = ['H','E','L','L','O','W','O','R','L','D']

P2 = ['W','E','L','C','O','M','E']
```

I want to exclude elements from the first collection if it exists it the second collection to get the result below

```
Result = ['H','R','D']
```

what will be the optimized and fast way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CombinePerKey`: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine

Python: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.5.0/apache_beam.transforms.core.html?highlight=combineperkey#apache_beam.transforms.core.CombinePerKey

Java: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Combine.PerKey.html

1. Convert P1 & P2 into tuples like this:

code:

```
P1 = [('H', 'P1'), ('E', 'P1'), ('L', 'P1'), ('L', 'P1'), ('O', 'P1'), ('W', 'P1'), ('O', 'P1'), ('R', 'P1'), ('L', 'P1'), ('D', 'P1')]

P2 = [('W', 'P2'), ('E', 'P2'), ('L', 'P2'), ('C', 'P2'), ('O', 'P2'), ('M', 'P2'), ('E', 'P2')]
```

2. Flatten the 2 p-collections together
3. pass the flattened p-collection into a `CombinePerKey`, with a `CombineFn` that marks if a string has in both p1 & p2:

code:

```
class IsInBoth(apache_beam.core.CombineFn):
    def _add_inputs(self, elements, accumulator=None):
        accumulator = accumulator or self.create_accumulator()
        for obj in elements:
            if obj == 'P1':
                accumulator['P1'] = True
            if obj == 'P2':
                accumulator['P2'] = True
        return accumulator

    def create_accumulator(self):
        return {'P1': False, 'P2': False}

    def add_input(self, accumulator, element, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._add_inputs(elements=[element], accumulator=accumulator)

    def add_inputs(self, accumulator, elements, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._add_inputs(elements=elements, accumulator=accumulator)

    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators, *args, **kwargs):
        return {
            'P1': any([i['P1'] for i in accumulators]),
            'P2': any([i['P2'] for i in accumulators])}

    def extract_output(self, accumulator, *args, **kwargs):
        return accumulator
```

4. filter out the results from `CombinePerKey` that have `{'P1': True, 'P2': True}`

Comment: I'm really appreciate your code, it's great and helped me to do a similar task. but according to the question the filter should be `{'P1': True, 'P2': False}`